# Expanding simple JSON returns list error jsonlite

Tags: r, json

Let´s suppose I have this dataframe:

```
accessed = c("{\"first\":\"2024-01-25T15:02:02\",\"last\":\"2024-01-25T15:20:08\"}","{\"first\":\"2023-11-09T08:07:11\",\"last\":\"2023-11-09T08:32:18\"}","{\"first\":\"2023-11-09T08:33:39\",\"last\":\"2023-11-10T16:03:38\"}")
col1 = c("a","b","c")
col2 = c("a","b","c")

df = data.frame(accessed, col1,col2)
```

When I try to expand the jason into two more columns through this code...

```
dfnew = df|> mutate(accessed = map(accessed, ~ jsonlite::fromJSON(.x) |> 
                                      unnest(everything())))
```

It returns an error that I don´t understand.

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `accessed = map(accessed, ~unnest(jsonlite::fromJSON(.x), everything()))`.
Caused by error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'unnest' applied to an object of class "list"
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

When I run the `map` of the JSON I see the map is correctly recognizing the two different columns `first` and `last`. Surprisingly I´ve used this method to expand JSON columns in the past and they were also lists and even lists of lists.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like: `df |> mutate(accessed = map(accessed, ~ jsonlite::fromJSON(.x) |> as.data.frame())) |> unnest(accessed)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the CRAN package [rjsoncons](https://mtmorgan.github.io/rjsoncons) I used `j_pivot()` to pivot each object to a column in a tibble; the current example does not require a 'path' argument to `j_pivot()`, because each row is the JSON object that we would like to pivot.

```
df |>
    pull(accessed) |>
    j_pivot(as = "tibble")
## # A tibble: 3 × 2
##   first               last               
##   <chr>               <chr>              
## 1 2024-01-25T15:02:02 2024-01-25T15:20:08
## 2 2023-11-09T08:07:11 2023-11-09T08:32:18
## 3 2023-11-09T08:33:39 2023-11-10T16:03:38
```

A more complete solution is

```
df |>
    bind_cols(
        df |>
        pull(accessed) |>
        j_pivot(as = "tibble")
    ) |>
    select(-accessed)
```